# Cannot access JavaScript Objects in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, object

Currently, I have a list named appointments initialized outside of a function, and my code is pushing objects into this array from within that function.

```
var appointments = [];
async function getAllAppointmentEvents() {
    var doctorList = await getAllDoctors();
    // For all doctors
    for (let i = 1; i < doctorList["doctorinfo"].length; i++) {
        // Find their appointments
        schedule = await getAppointmentsByDoctor(i).then(function (response) { return response; });
        // For each appointment
        if (schedule["schedules"] !== undefined) {
            for (let j = 0; j < schedule["schedules"].length; j++) {
                var startDate = new Date(schedule["schedules"][j]["datetime"]);
                // startDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("")
                var endDate = new Date(schedule["schedules"][j]["datetime"]);
                endDate.setHours(startDate.getHours() + 1);
                var result = {
                    title: doctorList["doctorinfo"][i][1],
                    start: startDate.toISOString().slice(0, 19),
                    end: endDate.toISOString().slice(0, 19),
                    color: "#C0C0C0",
                    groupId: doctorList["doctorinfo"][i][0]
                };
                appointments.push(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I console.log the output, I get an empty array that seems to contain all all the objects. But i'm unable to access the objects by `appointments[0]`. I've also tried printing out `Object.keys(appointments)` and it doesn't have any keys either. When I console.log inside the function, the array is accessible as per normal.

The output I get when I console.log the list from outside of the function: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s5Rk.png)

I need help accessing the objects from outside of the function. Thanks!

Comment: You need to post the code for your attempt at solving the issue.

Comment: Post your code, so that there will be a chance of quick answering.

Comment: Hi! Do you mean the entire file?

Comment: Where did you declare `appointments`?

Comment: I declared appointments outside of the function! I've updated the code to show that

Comment: Despite missing a [mcve], it's almost certain that you have a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score -1):

Your first for loop is a sychronous operation. At each operation it will run through the operations inside the loop block, and move onto the next iteration (i++, and repeat all).

Inside the synchronous loop, you have an asynchronous operation:

```
schedule = await getAppointmentsByDoctor(i).then(function (response) { return response; });
```

The sync loop doesn't work well with your async operation - probably why your array isn't filled up by the time you expect it to be.

You can use an implementation of Promise.all with the current async/await to solve your issue.

You can also look for an asyncForEach implementation, like in [this article](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404) and [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/Atinux/fd2bcce63e44a7d3addddc166ce93fb2).

Gist content in case it is removed:

```
const waitFor = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
const asyncForEach = async (array, callback) => {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array)
  }
}

const start = async () => {
  await asyncForEach([1, 2, 3], async (num) => {
    await waitFor(50)
    console.log(num)
  })
  console.log('Done')
}

start()
```

Comment: When giving an -1, if you explain why you did it, you'll be able to help me not repeat the same mistake.